# Pulling a range based on one criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I have a formula that allows me to join multiple rows together and remove duplicates:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!A:D, NOT(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(Sheet1!A:D), "n/a"))))))
```

The issue I'm running in to is because this references another tab in the same sheet, it cannot be sorted by different columns without changing the results.

So what I'd like to know is: how do I modify the above formula so that it pulls the data it needs based on criteria I give it? Note this will need to be across a range of cells and includes strings of text.

Comment: Okay - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1127X8O-UkIRyU5nTe-8vOGxyG1mqVTlLJqjNuOsaehY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I still don't understand what is your exact criteria. Could you give an example of your expected behavior? You could try to make this with Apps Script if you are comfortable with it.

Comment: Sure, sorry for the confusion.

In the sheet provided above you'll notice there are two tabs. In Sheet 1 I'm using the formula I provided in column G to join all values together, add a space in between each one, and remove any duplicate entries. And it's working great!

The issue is: on Sheet 2 I'm trying to match the same definitions to the correct word. So cat definition goes with cat, house with house, etc. This would be fine, except I need to sort by column B on either sheet from time to time and this messes up the results on the formula.

The criteria needs to be value in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comment I understand what you are trying to do. Basically you want to retrieve an information of the first sheet matching with your "row key".

Is there any reason why you haven't used a [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)?

For example using this formula:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:G, 7, FALSE), "VALUE NOT FOUND")
```

[image: Example of Use]

If you [sort](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) or randomize the range of column `B` you get a result like this:

[image: Randomize List]

In here you see that every description keeps up with its key.

---

**EDIT:** So after your comment it seems that you don't have your information inside a single cell. You could create this cell as a placeholder to later retrieve the information.

Or if you need you could make this inside the formula, that could make this a little messy but still could be workable.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, 
    UNIQUE(
        TRANSPOSE(
            FILTER({VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:G, 3, FALSE), VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:G, 4, FALSE), VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:G, 5, FALSE), VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:G, 6, FALSE)},
                   NOT(LOWER({VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:G, 3, FALSE), VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:G, 4, FALSE), VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:G, 5, FALSE), VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:G, 6, FALSE)}) = "n/a")
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Created Range]

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of characters on my last comment. Column G on Sheet 1 is only there as an example of what I'd like it to look like on Sheet 2. I'd like my result to only exist on Sheet 2.

Comment: Quite messy, but it gets the job done! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(B1:B), {QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 UNIQUE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(Sheet1!C:E="",,"♥"&ROW(Sheet1!C:C)&"♦"&Sheet1!C:E)),,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")), "♦"))), 
 "where not lower(Col2) matches 'n/a'", 0), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1")), "select Col1", 0), TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(Sheet1!C:E="",,"♥"&ROW(Sheet1!C:C)&"♦"&Sheet1!C:E)),,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")), "♦"))), 
 "where not lower(Col2) matches 'n/a'", 0), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0),,999^99))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but the criteria needs to be the value in column A, not column B. I'd like the sheet to be able to be sorted by column B on either sheet and still retain the same value in column C.